# How to make `include!` work with macros defined in external crates?

Tags: rust

When using [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) in stable as recommended by the [respective blog post](http://erickt.github.io/blog/2015/05/18/serde-0-dot-4-0-now-supports-macros-in-stable-rust/), one will have to use the built-in `include!` macro to pull in a file generated by [serde-codegen](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/tree/master/serde_codegen).

The [file linked here](https://github.com/Byron/yup-oauth2/blob/a260b13868aaf667ef5379e4223ec0c94b78e26b/src/lib.rs#L69) shows this in a more complex example which can use `rustc` *nightly* as well as `rustc` *stable*.

However, as the [docs of `include!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include!.html) suggest, it does not behave hygienically.

What this means was unclear to me until I ran into the issue that macros defined in an external crate, [yup-hyper-mock](https://github.com/Byron/yup-hyper-mock), were not defined at *include-time*. Some tests showed that even something like `extern crate foo-bar-snoo-snoo;` will not trigger an error at *include-time*, showing that it was not yet evaluated at all.

The problem arises from `include!` trying to expand macros, and failing if these are coming from external crates which haven't been evaluated yet.

An attempt of mine to define empty macros with the correct signature cause the `include!` macro to work, but the compile would fail later as `include!` would actually expand the macro right away, which was empty at the time of the include.

**Is there a way to make `include!` work with macros defined in external crates?** Alternatively, can you imagine a workaround to make my particular case work?

Personally I think `include!` should not expand macros at all, but leave that to the next compile step which should bring in external crates - maybe we are looking at a bug in `rustc`, but I am not sure about that.

## How to reproduce

Please note that both *stable* and *nightly* compilers show the same issues.

```
git clone --branch syntex https://github.com/Byron/yup-oauth2
cd yup-oauth2
git reset --hard f59d97d

# build and test fail because 'include!' runs before crates are pulled
# in, but still expands macros
cargo build
cargo test
```

## Meta

*stable*

```
➜  yup-oauth2 git:(syntex) rustc --version --verbose
rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: a59de37e99060162a2674e3ff45409ac73595c0e
commit-date: 2015-05-13
build-date: 2015-05-14
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.0.0
```

*nightly*

```
➜  yup-oauth2 git:(syntex) rustc --version --verbose
rustc 1.2.0-nightly (2228ce10c 2015-06-09)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 2228ce10c6d83c17b6346396aa7c7ef9082f1c04
commit-date: 2015-06-09
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.2.0-nightly
```

Comment: My solution for now will be to just not use macros in this case.

Comment: I am not sure whether this question is still relevant, as you mention rustc 1.0.0 here...